# Java 8 - Maven MissingResourceException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx-2, pom.xml

I have a JavaFX project using maven for building. This project is using resource locale files. 
So, I have over `src/main/resources/locale/strings_xxx.properties`.

This is working fine when running from IntelliJ. But when I'm trying to build a jar file with maven, it throws this exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
    Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name locale\strings, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.SystemConfiguration.<clinit>(SystemConfiguration.java:16)
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>testJFX</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20160212</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.systray.test</groupId>
           <artifactId>systray</artifactId>
           <version>0.1</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>${project.basedir}/Systray.jar</systemPath>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>

       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           </resource>
       </resources>

       <plugins>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
                   <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

       </plugins>

   </build>

</project>
```

SystemConfiguration.java is using ResourceBundle like this:

```
private ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("locale\\strings", Locale.getDefault());
```

Remember that running this app by IntelliJ is working just fine. What am I missing in this pom?